# Problema ionic 4 .present();

Tags: angular, ionic, typescript

Estou estudando ionic e estou na versão Ionic CLI : 4.12.0, estou enfrentando um problema no meu construtor da home, quando utilizando o metodo present() na minha variável loading apresenta o seguinte erro:
 "Property 'present' does not exist on type 'Promise'. Did you forget to use 'await'? "

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
          private _htpp: HttpClient,
          private _loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {


let loading = this._loadingCtrl.create({
  message: 'Carregando...' 
});

loading.present();
```

Alguém sabe me dizer como posso corrigir esse problema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christian, voce deveria englobar seu codigo do Toast em um metodo asincrono dessa forma...

```
async loadingToast() {
    const toast = await this._loadingCtrl.create({
        message: 'Carregando...' 
    });

    return await toast.present();
}
```